# how to print multiple print statements in same line print(json.dumps(i['name'])) in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have below python code, I want to divert all the print statements to be appear in one row in a file

```
import os
import requests
import json
import sys
with open('/home/yu/viewsLogdna.json') as f:
data=json.load(f)
 for i in data:
  if 'channels' in i:
    temp = i['channels'][0]
    if 'alertid' in temp:
        temp.pop('alertid')
for i in data:
 if "channels" in i.keys():
    print(json.dumps(i['name']))
    print(json.dumps(i['apps']))
    print(json.dumps(i['channels']))
```

Output should look like below

```
    name|apps|channels
```

Comment: can you send `json.dumps` ?

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
print(json.dumps(i['name']), 
      json.dumps(i['apps']), 
      json.dumps(i['channels']), 
      sep='|')
```

By default `print` would print with spaces between the arguments. `sep` argument overrides this with the symbol (or string) you want.

Comment: I'm running this code in Python 2.7.5, getting below error

    -sh-4.2$ python en-active-alerts-dis.py 
      File "en-active-alerts-dis.py", line 19
        sep='|')
       ^
     SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Python 2.7 is not maintained for a year and a half. I would strongly suggest switching to python3.5+. But the solution is `print('|'.join([json.dumps(i['name']), json.dumps(i['apps']), json.dumps(i['channels']]))`

Comment: I have managed with this code for time being, thanks a lot!

for i in data:
    if "channels" in i.keys():
        print(json.dumps(i['name']),
              json.dumps(i['apps']),
              json.dumps(i['channels']),
              json.dumps(i['viewid']),
              )

Answer (score 0):

One option would be the `csv` module, which is designed for this kind of output; despite the name, it can use any separators.

```
w = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|')
for i in data:
 if "channels" in i.keys():
    w.writerow(
        json.dumps(i['name']),
        json.dumps(i['apps']),
        json.dumps(i['channels']),
    )
```

(Depending on the data structures and the required file format, `csv.writer` or `csv.DictWriter` may be more convenient.)

Comment: for i in data:
    if "channels" in i.keys():
        print(json.dumps(i['name']),
              json.dumps(i['apps']),
              json.dumps(i['channels']),
              json.dumps(i['viewid']),
              )


I have managed with this code, thank you!

Comment: @yugreddy don't forget to mark the answer as the approved solution

Comment: @LotB, How can I mark the answer approved and close the issue?